# Incluir arquivos adicionais para a DLL com JNA

Tags: java

estou com um problema na execução de uma DLL no Java via JNA, a DLL busca um arquivo que está na mesma pasta chamado `"propriedades.properties"`, esta DLL funciona normalmente, mas ao utilizar o JNA ela não encontra o arquivo. Ao que parece o JNA executa a DLL em outro lugar, e não na sua pasta de origem ("Isso é apenas uma suposição de minha parte"). O código que utilizo segue abaixo:

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:\\");
        System.setProperty("jna.debug_load", "true");
        System.setProperty("jna.debug_load.jna", "true");

DllMicros micros = (DllMicros) Native.loadLibrary("dllmicros", DllMicros.class);

micros.CallSat(_Id, _ConfigVenda, _DadosVendas, _Error);
```

Ativei o debug para tentar identificar o problema, mas ele não dá indício alguma, uma vez que a DLL é incluída normalmente, de qualquer maneira incluirei ele também.

```
Looking in C:\jnidispatch.dll
Trying (via loadLibrary) jnidispatch
Looking in classpath from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@e2f2a for /com/sun/jna/win32-x86/jnidispatch.dll
Found library resource at jar:file:/E:/Desenvolvimento/Workspaces/trunk4.4/dll-test/lib/jna-4.2.1.jar!/com/sun/jna/win32-x86/jnidispatch.dll
Trying C:\Users\Ricardo\AppData\Local\Temp\jna--1433617560\jna2182820279403986556.dll
Found jnidispatch at C:\Users\Ricardo\AppData\Local\Temp\jna--1433617560\jna2182820279403986556.dll
Looking for library 'dllmicros'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: C:\
Trying C:\dllmicros.dll
Found library 'dllmicros' at C:\dllmicros.dll
Ocorreu um erro: O arquivo de propriedades n�o p�de ser carregado! // Este erro é lançado pela DLL que não encontra o arquivo na pasta em que está sendo executada
```

Se alguém tiver alguma dica, fico agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analisei toda a documentação do `JNA` e realmente não existe a possibilidade de anexar um arquivo para a execução da `DLL`, a solução que encontrei foi criar métodos na `DLL` para atribuir o caminho do arquivo de properties e assim não ficar dependente de ter ambos na mesma pasta durante a execução.